# How to decrypt a string encoded using JS webcrypto in php?

Tags: javascript, php, typescript, webcrypto-api

I'm trying to decrypt a string encrypted using webcrypto api with php.

This is how they're encrypted (`fromByteArray` is from package `base64-js`):

```js
public async encrypt(value: string): Promise<string> {
    const key: CryptoKeyPair = await this.database.getCryptoKey();
    const encoder: TextEncoder = new TextEncoder();
    const result: ArrayBuffer = await window.crypto.subtle.encrypt({
      name: 'RSA-OAEP',
    }, key.publicKey, encoder.encode(value));

    return fromByteArray(new Uint8Array(result));
  }
```

This is how the keys are made:

```js
public async createKey(): Promise<void> {
    const key = await window.crypto.subtle.generateKey({
      name: 'RSA-OAEP',
      modulusLength: 4096,
      publicExponent: new Uint8Array([0x01, 0x00, 0x01]),
      hash: 'SHA-512'
    }, true, ['encrypt', 'decrypt']);
    await this.database.storeCryptoKey(key);
  }
```

And this is how they're exported:

```js
public async exportKey(): Promise<string> {
    const key = await this.database.getCryptoKey();
    const privateKey = key.privateKey;
    const publicKey = key.publicKey;

    const exportedPrivateKey = fromByteArray(new Uint8Array(await window.crypto.subtle.exportKey('pkcs8', privateKey)));
    const exportedPublicKey = fromByteArray(new Uint8Array(await window.crypto.subtle.exportKey('spki', publicKey)));

    return `${exportedPrivateKey}:::${exportedPublicKey}`;
  }
```

Note that decryption in Javascript works, so it's not an issue of storing the data incorrectly.

Now for the php side, this is how I try to decrypt:

```php
public function decrypt(OpenSSLAsymmetricKey $decryptionKey, string $encryptedData): string
    {
        $encryptedData = base64_decode($encryptedData);

        $success = openssl_private_decrypt($encryptedData, $decrypted, $decryptionKey, OPENSSL_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING);

        if (!$success) {
            throw new RuntimeException('Decryption failed');
        }

        return $decrypted;
    }
```

`$success` is false and thus the exception gets thrown.

The private key is created as such:

```php
public function getPrivateKey(User $user): OpenSSLAsymmetricKey
    {
        $privateKey = $this->getPrivateKeyString($user);

        $privateKeyContent = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
            . chunk_split($privateKey, 64, "\n")
            . "-----END PRIVATE KEY-----";
        return openssl_pkey_get_private($privateKeyContent)
            ?: throw new RuntimeException('Failed getting private key');
    }
```

The private key is taken from the joint string exported from typescript:

```php
private function getPrivateKeyString(User $user): string
    {
        return $user->getEncryptionKey() !== null
            ? explode(':::', $user->getEncryptionKey())[0]
            : throw new RuntimeException('No encryption keys stored');
    }
```

If someone wants to play around with it a bit, I can provide a private key and encrypted string (it's on localhost with test data).

Comment: PHP/OpenSSL does not support SHA256 for OAEP and certainly not SHA512 but only SHA-1. Both codes are therefore incompatible. Another option is phpseclib, which allows the specification of the digest.

Comment: Shouldn't I get an error on this `openssl_pkey_get_private($privateKeyContent)`? Anyway, I tried with phpseclib as well but didn't manage to make it work. I'll try phpseclib again and update the question with the updated code.